# unique for a block doesn't remove duplicates

Tags: rebol, rebol3

The strings are part of urls of which I stripped out the base.
`parse` detects four urls in some `html` file.  I've narrowed down the problem to this:

```
REBOL []
images: [{,W,H,wi,1TV1Rvu8EF9FDdUxKy+hTKK/RNifw3WQDJEI/sYkX78tyNifGd0/U4RpaBox1rO448B4dv24sYoTgxOMVC7Lz5J9sJXlk0nkM89n55HzX7qbRiX/cSkd3lepAEIj3LVTN7gmQLCI2+INwwg18IyDklZ3VZWkw011+77dkfgTTRlRaY397ricx4dk4BTHvCLZ} {,W,H,wi,1TV1Rvu8EF9FDdUxKy+hTKK/RNifw3WQDJEI/sYkX78tyNifGd0/U4RpaBox1rO448B4dv24sYoTgxOMVC7Lz5J9sJXlk0nkM89n55HzX7qbRiX/cSkd3lepAEIj3LVTN7gmQLCI2+INwwg18IyDklZ3VZWkw011+77dkfgTTRlRaY397ricx4dk4BTHvCLZ} {,W,H,wi,1TV1Rvu8EF9FDdUxKy+hTKK/RNifw3WQDJEI/sYkX78wvYn3cKtEeN/9Y8EfNR8J48B4dv24sYoTgxOMVC7Lz5J9sJXlk0nkM89n55HzX7qbRiX/cSkd3lepAEIj3LVTN7gmQLCI2+INwwg18IyDklZ3VZWkw011+77dkfgTTRlRaY397ricx4dk4BTHvCLZ} {,W,H,wi,1TV1Rvu8EF9FDdUxKy+hTKK/RNifw3WQDJEI/sYkX78wvYn3cKtEeN/9Y8EfNR8J48B4dv24sYoTgxOMVC7Lz5J9sJXlk0nkM89n55HzX7qbRiX/cSkd3lepAEIj3LVTN7gmQLCI2+INwwg18IyDklZ3VZWkw011+77dkfgTTRlRaY397ricx4dk4BTHvCLZ}]

print join "before: " length? images
unique images
print join "after: " length? images

print join "1=2? " images/1 = images/2
print join "1=3? " images/1 = images/3
print join "1=4? " images/1 = images/4
print join "2=3? " images/2 = images/3
print join "2=4? " images/2 = images/4
print join "3=4? " images/3 = images/4
```

As can be seen, urls 1 and 2 are identical, and the same can be said to urls 3 and 4.  Still, `unique` doesn't remove the duplicates.  Why does this happen, how to deal with it?

Comment: I think that if something modifies, it should be a verb.  There are some violations, like **exclude** and **intersect** do not modify.  *(In that case, I'd think that exclude should probably modify, but intersect should be renamed to "intersection")*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNIQUE` does not modify original series. Whether function modifies is usually mentioned in it's help string, see `SORT` for example. Just set your block to the result of `UNIQUE`, like this:

```
>> a: [1 2 3 4 3 4 4] 
== [1 2 3 4 3 4 4]
>> unique a           
== [1 2 3 4]
>> a                  
== [1 2 3 4 3 4 4]
>> a: unique a          
== [1 2 3 4]
>> a
== [1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: I must have confounded the modify/not modify with `sort` or other word.  Thanks.

Comment: It's always safer to expect that function does not modify and assign the result.